# How do I extract all matches with a Tcl regex?

Tags: regex, tcl

hi everybody i want solution for this regular expression, my problem is  Extract all the hex numbers in the form `H'xxxx`, i used this regexp but i didn't get all hexvalues only i get one number, how to get whole hex number from this string

```
set hex "V5CCH,IA=H'22EF&H'2354&H'4BD4&H'4C4B&H'4D52&H'4DC9"
set res [regexp -all {H'([0-9A-Z]+)&} $hex match hexValues]
puts "$res H$hexValues"
```

i am getting output is 5 H4D52

Comment: Does the single quote need to be escaped, i wonder?: H\'([0-9A-Z]+)\&

Comment: If you are dealing with hex numbers, [0-9A-F] should suffice.

Comment: @Zabba, a single quote has no special meaning in a regex, or even in Tcl generally.

Comment: @relet, this works too:  `[[:xdigit:]]` -- http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/re_syntax.htm#M31

Answer (score 29, accepted):

#### On `-all -inline`

From [the documentation](http://www.hume.com/html84/mann/regexp.html):

> `-all` :  Causes the regular expression to be matched as many times as possible in the string, returning the total number of matches found. If this is specified with match variables, *they will contain information for the last match only*.
>
> `-inline` : Causes the command to return, as a list, the data that would otherwise be placed in match variables. When using `-inline`, *match variables may not be specified*. If used with `-all`, the list will be concatenated at each iteration, such that *a flat list is always returned*. For each match iteration, the command will append the overall match data, plus one element for each subexpression in the regular expression.

Thus to return all matches --including captures by groups-- as a flat list in Tcl, you can write:

```
set matchTuples [regexp -all -inline $pattern $text]
```

If the pattern has groups `0…N-1`, then each match is an `N`-tuple in the list. Thus the number of actual matches is the length of this list divided by `N`. You can then use `foreach` with `N` variables to iterate over each tuple of the list.

If `N = 2` for example, you have:

```
set numMatches [expr {[llength $matchTuples] / 2}]

foreach {group0 group1} $matchTuples {
   ...
}
```

#### References

- [regular-expressions.info/Tcl](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tcl.html)

---

#### Sample code

Here's a solution for this specific problem, annotated with output as comments ([see also on ideone.com](http://ideone.com/n2BCB)):

```
set text "V5CCH,IA=H'22EF&H'2354&H'4BD4&H'4C4B&H'4D52&H'4DC9"
set pattern {H'([0-9A-F]{4})}
 
set matchTuples [regexp -all -inline $pattern $text]
 
puts $matchTuples
# H'22EF 22EF H'2354 2354 H'4BD4 4BD4 H'4C4B 4C4B H'4D52 4D52 H'4DC9 4DC9
# \_________/ \_________/ \_________/ \_________/ \_________/ \_________/
#  1st match   2nd match   3rd match   4th match   5th match   6th match
 
puts [llength $matchTuples]
# 12
 
set numMatches [expr {[llength $matchTuples] / 2}]
puts $numMatches
# 6
 
foreach {whole hex} $matchTuples {
   puts $hex
}
# 22EF
# 2354
# 4BD4
# 4C4B
# 4D52
# 4DC9
```

---

#### On the pattern

Note that I've changed the pattern slightly:

- Instead of `[0-9A-Z]+`, e.g. `[0-9A-F]{4}` is more specific for matching exactly 4 hexadecimal digits
- If you insist on matching the `&`, then the last hex string (`H'4DC9` in your input) can not be matched

  - This explains why you get `4D52` in the original script, because that's the last match with `&`
  - Maybe get rid of the `&`, or use `(&|$)` instead, i.e. a `&` or the end of the string `$`.

#### References

- [regular-expressions.info/Finite Repetition](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html), [Anchors](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html)

Comment: thanks, i don't know count of hexa decimal in that situation how to evaluate?

Comment: @polygen i tried with array manipulation the array size display only once that one last element is stored in that one, could you please provide example that one.

Comment: @polygene: I suggest you edit that into your answer, as it's the idiomatic method.

Comment: @polygene: +1: Looks pretty good. If you're writing more Tcl, remember to put braces round expressions (unless you *really* know what you're doing) because that lets them be compiled and avoids problems that are similar in flavor to SQL injection attacks; braced expressions are hazard-free and fast.

Comment: @Donal fellows how to use -about option in regexp

Comment: @Malli: `regexp -about $RE` returns a two-item list describing features of the RE. One item is the number of capturing groups, the other is a list of features (actually a dump of the RE's internal `flags` field bits). If you want more info, ask a question properly!

Answer (score 2):

I'm not Tclish, but I think you need to use both the `-inline` and `-all` options:

```
regexp -all -inline {H'([0-9A-Z]+)&} $string
```

EDIT: Here it is again, this time with a corrected regex (see the comments):

```
regexp -all -inline {H'[0-9A-F]+&} $string
```

Comment: but -inline output gives similar to 
regexp -all {H'(0-9A-Z]+)&} $string match
puts $match 
we can also write this one. the above regexp is produce H'22EF& 22EF H'2354& 2354 H'4BD4& 4BD4 H'4C4B& 4C4B H'4D52& 4D52
i don't want this output i need only that hexadecmial values

Comment: I was only demonstrating the use of `-all -inline`, but @poly is right: you need to get rid of those parentheses.  They aren't needed for grouping, and they're adding a lot of unwanted substrings to the results array.