# TCL - split string by arbitrary number of whitespaces to a list

Tags: list, split, whitespace, tcl

Say I have a string like this:

```
set str "AAA    B C     DFG 142               56"
```

Now I want to get a list as follows:

```
{AAA B C DFG 142 56}
```

For that I want to use split function, but in that case I get some extra empty lists {}. How I can get the list above?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
set text "Some arbitrary text which might include \$ or {"
set wordList [regexp -inline -all -- {\S+} $text]
```

See this: [Splitting a String Into Words](http://wiki.tcl.tk/989).

Comment: Wow, I didn't know `regexp` could return a list. I would have done this, which is almost as good `[split [regsub { {2,}} $string " "] " "]`. The regsub replaces all sequences of spaces of length 2 or more with a single space, then the split splits on that.

Comment: set wordList [regexp -inline -all -- {\S+} $text] here what does "--" mean?

Comment: That's necessary in case the regex begins with a "-" character, plus it's just a good habit to get into (for this plus many Tcl commands where the first non-switch argument can be perhaps user-input: `file delete -- $file`, `switch -exact -- $word`, ...)

Comment: BTW see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3369458/how-do-i-extract-all-matches-with-a-tcl-regex   and http://www.hume.com/html84/mann/regexp.html for -all and -inline flags.

Answer (score 9):

You can always do the following:

```
set str "AAA    B C     DFG 142               56"
set newStr [join $str " "]
```

It will output the following:

```
{AAA B C DFG 142 56}
```

Comment: Why does it work? As I know join - Create a string by joining together list elements, but your output is a list? and your input not a list... It is strange...

Comment: String, list, its all the same thing (technically). The output that was given, can easily be split into separate list elements, etc. You want your output to be a list though, don't you?

Comment: This works because the input can be parsed as a valid list. Had the input been "AAA }B  C   DFG  142   56", it would fail because that can't be parsed as a list.

Answer (score 5):

The [textutil::split](http://tcllib.sourceforge.net/doc/textutil_split.html) module from [tcllib](http://tcllib.sourceforge.net/doc/index.html) has a `splitx` proc that does exactly what you want

```
package require textutil::split
set result [textutil::split::splitx $str]
```

Answer (score 2):

As of Tcl 8.5, the following also works:

```
list {*}$str
```

(provided the string is also a proper list, as in the question). The output is the desired list.

Documentation:
[list](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/list.htm),
[{*} (syntax)](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/Tcl.htm)

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old, but in case others come across this in the future I'll add my solution. I subbed the unknown number of whitespace into one character of whitespace to allow split to work correctly, similar to Scott's answer:

```
set str "AAA    B C     DFG 142               56"    
regsub -all { +} $str " " str ; # str is now "AAA B C DFG 142 56"
set splitout [split $str { +}] ; # Split on one or more spaces.
```