# Regex exp doesn't match the test string

Tags: regex, tcl

I have a file that looks like this:

```
    0 1.6e-10 4.47e-10 7.94e-10 0.082080 rad:12 zzz_yy_x2 name/123 A1=0
    0 1.6e-10 0 7.94e-10 0.0 taa:12 yy_x2 name/540
```

However the regex doesn't seem to be matching the first 7 columns

```
if {[regexp {\s+?(.*?)\s+?(.*?)\s+?(.*?)\s+?(.*?)\s+?(.*?)\s+?(.*?)\s+?(.*?)} $line -> i s l t a c l n]} {
        echo $i $s $l $t $a $c $l $n
    }
```

Comment: What are the ***first 7 columns*** ?

Comment: In line 1 columns are separated by commas : 0, 1.6e-10, 4.47e-10, 7.94e-10, 0.082080, rad:12, zzz_yy_x2. There are no commas in reality

Comment: Do you really need to to use a regexp? Doesn't TCL have a function for splitting a string into an array at whitespace boundaries?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TCL - split string by arbitrary number of whitespaces to a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5728656/tcl-split-string-by-arbitrary-number-of-whitespaces-to-a-list)

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
lassign $line i s l t a c l n
```

Assuming that you don't have strange punctuation in your string (curly braces, etc.), most TCL functions that expect a list argument will also take a string with items separated by spaces and treat it as a list. The "lassign" function takes each item in a list and assigns it to a variable.

Also, I don't know if you meant to reuse the "l" variable. I think that both the regexp and the lassign will store the third item in "l" and immediately overwrite it with the seventh item in the list.

Comment: Please explain more about why this is a solution. _It might be one_ but good answers are usually more than just code.