# How to match the regexp globally in a file

Tags: tcl

I am having a file say text.txt having similar blocks of patterns like

```
<tr> I am nitesh goyal <\tr> nothing nothing <tr> I logged in stackoverflow<\tr> nothing nothing <tr> I want help to solve this <\tr> anyhting anything.
```

I want to take all the blocks data<\tr>.

currently i am using the regexp

```
I stored the file in a variable buffer
regexp "tr.*?\\tr" $buffer
```

But it is giving only fist block. How to take all the blocks present with the same delimiter.

Is it possible to have one block at a time and do some operations and then take second and so on.

Comment: Is that an attempt at HTML?  Your tags aren't matched and `\\` does not belong in the terminating tag.

Comment: yes i am attempting to do some operations on html file. i stored the file in a variable and want to do some operations on particular blocks

Comment: I think the answer to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3369458/how-do-i-extract-all-matches-with-a-tcl-regex) question might do the trick

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `-all -inline` options. In this case `regexp` command will return the list of all blocks it found.

```
set list_of_found_blocks [regexp -all -inline -- "tr.*?\\t" $buffer]
```

Comment: can i have one block at a time and do some operation and then take the second block. How to do that

Comment: @Nitesh, the variable `list_of_found_blocks` is a list, so you can just iterate over it using `foreach`