# Regular expression in TCL scripting

Tags: regex, tcl

I need to match "data arrival" multiple times in the string 
"data arrival time data arrival data arrival time data arrival data arrival time"

I have executed the below TCL code

Code:

```
set a "data arrival time data arrival data arrival time data arrival data arrival time"

regexp {(data arrival)*} $a match

puts $match
```

However i'm getting data arrival only once.
Please help me out to get desired result

Comment: That is trying to match the string "data arrival" or "data arrivaldata arrival".

Comment: Please check my answer and let know if it is enough or you need more details.

Answer (score 0):

You only search for 0 or more *consecutive* occurrences of `data arrival` substring with your regex.

You just need to find multiple matches, see [example code](https://ideone.com/iGVjzk):

```
set a {data arrival time data arrival data arrival time data arrival data arrival time}
set RE {data arrival}
set match [regexp -all -inline $RE $a]
puts $match
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify that you want to search for ALL occurences that match the string. Read more here: [How do I extract all matches with a Tcl regex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3369458/how-do-i-extract-all-matches-with-a-tcl-regex)