# /bin/expect $expect_out multiple regex matches

Tags: regex, expect

I'm using the following [expect(1)](https://linux.die.net/man/1/expect) script to receive a list of users on a Teamspeak server using the [Telnet Server Query](https://forum.teamspeak.com/threads/91465-How-to-use-the-Server-Query).

```sh
#!/usr/bin/expect

# Spawn TELNET
spawn telnet example.com 10000
expect "TS3"

# Login
send "login $USER $PASS\r"

# Set serverID
send "use sid=$SSID\r"
expect "error id=0 msg=ok"

# Get clients
send "clientlist\r"
```

This produces an output like this:

```
clid=512 cid=3 client_database_id=4 client_nickname=User1 client_type=1|clid=486 cid=3 client_database_id=26 client_nickname=User2 client_type=0
```

Then, I can use the following code to get the client id (**clid=***) of the **first** user;

```sh
# Get clients
send "clientlist\r"
expect -re "clid=(\\d+) "
set clid $expect_out(1,string)
puts "$clid"
# Output: 512
```

**Questions**:

- How can I get a list of all the client ids (**clid=***)
- Can I loop over them using a `for`/`foreach`?

---

I've tried to use the accepted answer in this question: [How do I extract all matches with a Tcl regex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3369458/how-do-i-extract-all-matches-with-a-tcl-regex), however I'm so far unable to apply it on the output of a `send`, instead of a variable

Comment: Does the client list show up as a single line, pipe-delimited?

Comment: @glennjackman Yes, it's all on 1 line: `<User 1 params>|<User 2 params>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways to handle this, but the most natural might be to go by these steps: first, instead of separate `expect` and `set` lines, use the facility of doing the `set`  as result of a match:

```tcl
expect -re "clid=(\\d+) " { set clid $expect_out(1,string) }
puts "$clid"
```

This is slightly better as `clid` will only be set if the pattern matches.
The next step is then to use the command `exp_continue` to restart the matching process. It is like a `for` loop. See `man expect`.

```tcl
expect -re "clid=(\\d+) " { 
 set clid $expect_out(1,string)
 puts "$clid"
 exp_continue
}
```

To make `clid` into a list (which in tcl is really just a string), use the list commands:

```tcl
expect -re "clid=(\\d+) " { 
 lappend clid $expect_out(1,string)
 exp_continue
}
puts "$clid"
```

Now you can iterate through the list with

```tcl
foreach id $clid { puts $id }
```

You should now think about how to detect the end of the output of the `clientlist` command, so that you can match it instead of stopping due to a timeout.
(Post a new question if blocked in your progress).

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'm able to loop over all the ID's. The *you should now think about how to detect the end of the output of the clientlist command* still needs some debugging, I'll guess I'll need to research the behaviour of `exp_continue` some more! I'll accept your answer if there aren't any other solutions posted.w

Answer (score 0):

expect uses `\r\n` as line endings. Try this:

```
send "clientlist\r"
expect -re {clientlist\r\n(.+)\r\n}
set ids {}
foreach {_ id} [regexp -all -inline {clid=(\d+)} $expect_out(1,string)] {
    lappend ids $id
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Unfortunately, I'm not able to see any of the IDs using this approach.