# Tcl regex extracting all to a list

Tags: regex, tcl

I am trying to collect all of the matches then loop through them to get the correct. When I loop I only get the first capture `04:04:01.121`

[Modeled After](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3369458/how-do-i-extract-all-matches-with-a-tcl-regex)

```
set fileData "here is more stuf
04:04:01.121 Found Me 1
this is nothing
04:04:01.122 Found Me 2
this is nothing 1
04:04:01.123 Found Me 3
this is nothing 2
04:04:01.124 Found Me 4
this is nothing 3
04:04:01.125 Found Me 5
this is nothing 4
04:04:01.126 Found Me 6"
set testRegEx "(\\d{2}:\\d{2}:\\d{2}.\\d{3}).*Found Me"
set regexList [regexp -nocase -all -inline $testRegEx $fileData]
foreach {whole item} $regexList {
    puts "-----$item"
}
```

Comment: Additionally to the good advice below, you can capture the list of items with [`lmap`](https://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/lmap.htm) -- `set items [lmap {_ item} [regexp -nocase -all -inline -line $testRegEx $fileData] {set item}]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is not only the *greed* of the `*` quantifier. The reason is that in Tcl, by default, the `.` metacharacter also matches a newline. But if you add `(?p)` to the beginning of the regular expression, this will not happen. More info [here](https://www.regular-expressions.info/tcl.html).

```
set fileData "here is more stuf
04:04:01.121 Found Me 1
this is nothing
04:04:01.122 Found Me 2
this is nothing 1
04:04:01.123 Found Me 3
this is nothing 2
04:04:01.124 Found Me 4
this is nothing 3
04:04:01.125 Found Me 5
this is nothing 4
04:04:01.126 Found Me 6"
set testRegEx {(?p)(\d{2}(?::\d{2}){2}\.\d{3}).*Found Me}
set regexList [regexp -nocase -all -inline $testRegEx $fileData]
foreach {whole item} $regexList {
    puts "-----${item}"
}
```

Results:

```
-----04:04:01.121
-----04:04:01.122
-----04:04:01.123
-----04:04:01.124
-----04:04:01.125
-----04:04:01.126
```

Try it on [rextester](https://rextester.com/ROJM33933).

Comment: Passing the `-line` option to `regexp` would have helped too here; it makes nothing match a newline (except an explicit `\n`).

Answer (score 0):

Repetition operators like `*` are *greedy*; they match as much as possible. So your RE matches the `04:04:01.121` at the beginning and the last `Found Me`, with everything else consumed by the `.*`.

Try:

```
set testRegEx "(\\d{2}:\\d{2}:\\d{2}.\\d{3}) Found Me"
```

instead.